# IP camera jpg stream to post

Tags: posts, automation

what are your ideas on grabbing an ip webcams jpg image (which is updated every few seconds) and automatically posting it via wordpress. What would be the best approach?

Basically I would like to grab a jpg image, create a new post and create a post image from the webcam jpg found at a certain URL so you get a number of image-posts.

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: You'll need Flash. See [this](http://www.taboca.com/p/camcanvas/) page

Comment: I am talking about an ip cam. There is no local access but an URL where I can grab the jpg from.

Comment: then it's even easier, just request the data from that URL using wp's [http apis](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) and store it in a image file...

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding a post every few seconds, then you'd really spam your database. Adding an attachment (which is some type of post), is not really different, but more appreciated. Take a look at [these](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src#Related) functions.

Just my 2 cents: I'd just display it according to the url, not download, save and add a post with lots of unnecessary data. If you need to save it, you're better off with simply saving it in some custom folder and not use the wp engine at this point. You could create date and/or time based folders and use the folder name as img caption or such.